# How to solve "dbt: error unrecognised arguments: --schema"?

Tags: python, dbt

Here I am using windows laptop with python version 3.10.4 and dbt version 1.1.1 while running this command '''***dbt --schema***'''in cmd I am getting error as '''***dbt: error: unrecognized arguments: --schema***'''

Comment: I don't use `dbt`, but according to [the CLI docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/cli-overview): "*Most command-line tools, including dbt, have a `--help` flag that you can use to show available commands and arguments.*". Maybe it's supposed to be `dbt <cmd> --schema`.

Comment: what are you trying to do? dbt does not have a `--schema` option at the command line